# getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: when using spark-submit

Tags: spark-streaming, spark-submit

I am getting the following error using `spark-submit` in local mode,

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.mytwitter.spark.TwitterStreaming

The error occurs when I use this command in terminal,

`spark-submit --class com.mytwitter.spark.TwitterStreaming /home/hadoop/workspace/Twitter/target/Twitter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`

Comment: Please note I have made jar using mvn clean package assembly:single...can someone please guide me where I have been doing mistake...

Comment: Can you try 'mvn clean compile assembly:single' ?

Comment: @Saravanan: I tried this but still getting same error.

Comment: Can you share the pom.xml ?

Comment: try https://pastebin.com/ if it doesn't contain any sensitive info

Comment: Thanks, however please download from this link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PLzJ_3BLYotCpElw22ukmiz6Z7LQyuJB/view?usp=drivesdk